# I always accidentally log out of my session via shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, session, logout

So I have Ubuntu 14.04, with GNOME Desktop Environment (downloaded from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback/)).

Sometimes, when I'm working, I accidentally press a combination of keys which logs me out of my session, closing all of my programs. I can't even identify what is the shortcut to do this.

I would like to change it, so it doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have pressed the Ctrl + Alt + L. 
You can remap keyboard shortcuts by using the System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, then you will find it in System tab.

Comment: This is certainly a possibility, I always try to clear the console with Ctrl + L, so this make sense. But the effect I always have is that all windows are close, but looking at the shortcuts, it seems that Ctrl + Alt + Del could be another option (although it's also a little rare, because when I press that combination there is a prompt first, before doing anything). So anyway, I decided to disable both shortcuts, I hope that works. Thank you.